# Vue markdown Image not displaying

Tags: image, vue.js, markdown

I'm using the [vue-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-markdown) package to render markdown. It seems to work except the images don't display. The file path is correct as I can have an `img` show up correctly

```
<img src="@/assets/7801_4_lang_image.png"><!-- shows up -->
<vue-markdown>![img](@/assets/7801_4_lang_image.PNG)</vue-markdown><!-- doesn't show up -->
```

Changing the `@` to `..` doesn't change anything either, the top one displays but the bottom one doesn't. The case of png/PNG also doesn't matter. Am I referencing the image wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The file loader doesn't know about images in Markdown so Webpack doesn't know to bundle them.

Typically you need to `require()` the image source (see https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)

You could try this but I'm not entirely sure if it will work with the *vue-markdown* component.

```
![img]({{ require('@/assets/7801_4_lang_image.PNG') }})
```

To use the `source` prop, you would use something like

```html
<vue-markdown :source="`![img](${require('@/assets/7801_4_lang_image.PNG')})`">
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

---

You could also use [the public folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) who's contents are always bundled. For example, for a file `public/images/7801_4_lang_image.PNG` and assuming your app runs at the domain root

```
![img](/images/7801_4_lang_image.PNG)
```

Comment: the first option works if I put that between the tags `<vue-markdown>` but if it comes as a string and is loaded through `:source` the `{}` get encoded to `%7B%7D` and the image doesn't load again. Do you have any other ideas?